# iAd integration done but no option when binary is uploaded

Tags: ios, binary, app-store-connect, iad

I had signed in for iAds, filled in all the details(tax,contact us,bank). iAds are enabled for me.Test ads are displayed in my app.But when I uploaded my app it never asked me about any ad integration. Is it understood that they will work once the app is on the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the iAds will work once your app is live on the app store. I wasn't asked for any ad integration when i uploaded to the app store. My ads started to appear after 24hrs of the app being live on the app store.